# Regarding geometric property to be satisfied when angle is right angle.

Tags: geometry

I am self studying number theory but I could not think about this argument in proof of a result. This argument is related to high school geometry but unfortunately I couldn't think about it.

Image of diagram to be used has been added and could be found at end.

> Statement to be proved: If $AD= √(aa')$ , $BD= a'$, $DC= a$, then show that angle $\hat{BAC}=90°$ .

Please give some hint..

[image]

Comment: Is it also given that $AD \perp BC$? If so can you use Pythagoras theorem and find the hypotenuses of smaller triangles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$AC^2=DC^2+AD^2$

$AB^2=BD^2+AD^2$

Now check if $AC^2+AB^2=BC^2$?

If so, it will be right.

($AD$ must be a height)

Answer (score 0):

You may use Pythagoras theorem but here is an alternative using coordinate geometry.
 Choose the origin at $A$ and show the dot product equals $0$  :
$$AB\cdot AC = (-a',-\sqrt{aa'}) \cdot (a, -\sqrt{aa'}) =0$$

[image]